# Strange behaviour from AutoHotKey opening CTRL+ALT+DEL menu

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create an AutoHotKey script to run some Premiere Pro shortcuts when I press Ctrl+Alt+d but for some reason it opens the Ctrl+Alt+Del windows menu instead. Hoping someone can debug because I can't figure it out.

Here's the script:

```
^!d::
Send, {Shift down}NumpadDiv{Shift up}
Send, {Shift down}1{Shift up}
Send, {NumpadDiv}
Send, {Shift down}3{Shift up}
Send, {Ctrl down}a{Ctrl up}
Send, {Delete}
Send, {Shift down}1{Shift up}
Send, {Up}
Send, {Enter}
Send, {Down}
Send, {Backspace 3}
Send, SEL
Send, {Enter}
Send, {Down}
Send, {Backspace 11}
Send, STR
Send, {Tab}
Send, {Shift down}o{Shift up}
Send, {Shift down}2{Shift up}
Send, {Shift down}n{Shift up}
return
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by adding

```
KeyWait Control
KeyWait Alt
```

To the beginning of my script